graphlearners doesn't work in conterfactual packages
My code is showed below:
prc_rf_lrn <- lrn("classif.ranger",predict_type="prob", importance="impurity")
graph_rf <- prc_rf_lrn %>>% po("threshold") 
graph_rf$plot()
learners_rf <- GraphLearner$new(graph_rf)

learners_rf 's predict_type is response, prob
GraphLearner:classif.ranger.threshold

Model: list
Parameters: classif.ranger.importance=impurity, classif.ranger.max.depth=4, classif.ranger.min.node.size=30,
classif.ranger.mtry=4, classif.ranger.num.threads=1, classif.ranger.num.trees=400, threshold.thresholds=0.4444
Packages: mlr3, mlr3pipelines, mlr3learners, ranger
Predict Types: [response], prob
Feature Types: logical, integer, numeric, character, factor, ordered, POSIXct
Properties: featureless, hotstart_backward, hotstart_forward, importance, loglik, missings, multiclass, oob_error,
selected_features, twoclass, weights

But when I use Counterfactual packages, it went wrong:
predictor1 <- Predictor$new(learners_rf, data=dat1, y="Prostate_cancer", type="prob")


Warning: Output seems to be class instead of probabilities.
Automatically transformed to 0 and 1 probabilities.
You might want to set predict.type = 'prob' for Learner!

So my results are strange.How to solve it?
I want to make the graphlearner's predict type be "prob".

As far as I can see you don't need the threshold pipeop here, as this really just transforms the probability into a classification. So just remove the threshold pipeop.
